# How to create a backup in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I was trying to create a WindowsAzure backup but I have no success because only create tables structure without data. This is the procedure which I was following:

```
1.Select the database you want to back up in new portal of windows azure https://manage.windowsazure.com
2.In the footer you will have an option to import/export. Click export. This opens a modal popup. Select the storage account you want to use and type in a appropriate name to save the *.bacpac file.
3.Once the file is saved to storage, download it to local, open sql server 2012 management studio. Select the database server. Right click on it and in the context menu you will find Import Data-Tier Application. Select the bacpac file from you local and follow the settings.
```

How can I create a backup but also saving the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE DATABASE XXXXXX AS COPY OF YYYYY`

MSDN link has a full article on all the different ways you can do this, the above is only one of them.
LMGTFY: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624.aspx

Comment: That will keep the data won't it? He asked to keep the table structure but without the data. Although, to work around this, we simply drop all the data manually...not sure if there is a better way around it!

Comment: I thought keeping the data was what the OP was asking about - "How can I create a backup but also saving the data?". There are easier ways though to get just the schema if you do NOT want the data.

Comment: I totally didn't read his original question correctly, so you are 100% correct, +1! It's been a long day where I am.

Comment: np i feel ya on long days!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches apart from the T-SQL scripted approach, two provided by Red Gate are:

- [SQL Azure Backup Application](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/download) - A free desktop application, as well as a command line tool, that allows you to transfer a complete backup of an SQL Azure database to your local environment, or another environment thta you have access to.
- [SQL Azure Backup Hosted](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/) - A hosted solution variant, which has a number of features

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently did a pretty comprehensive blog covering all the ways to backup a SQL Azure database.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_technical_support_wats_team/archive/2013/03/04/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Just so you know - I develop option number 7 :)